# Does a Oracle with the Lich curse get a reduced-cost phylactery?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, curses, oracle

One of the Oracle's curses is Lich; someone with this curse is almost but not quite a [Lich](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lich/). The only way I know of creating a Lich is by constructing the 120,000 gp phylactery; since this oracle has met most conditions, do they get a discount?

The Oracle's [Lich](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/oracle-curses#TOC-Lich) curse description says:

> Every living spellcaster hides a secret in their flesh—a unique, personalized set of conditions that, when all are fulfilled in the correct order, can trigger the transformation into a lich. Normally, one must expend years and tens of thousands of gold pieces to research this deeply personalized method of attaining immortality. Yet, in a rare few cases, chance and ill fortune can conspire against an unsuspecting spellcaster.
>
> You have (unknowingly) fulfilled most (but not all) of the ritualistic components to achieve lichdom. You have yet to turn into an undead creature, but you are close. You take damage from positive energy and heal from negative energy as if you were undead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maybe

While the rules about lichdom in the bestiary are quite simple, we have seen *several* ways in the lore of Golarion about people becoming [liches](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Lich) in weird circunstances.

> The process itself is a quite difficult and lengthy one, as no two liches achieve their undead state by the same method. (...) As no two bodies or souls are the same, each of these processes are unique to the individual; what has worked in the past might kill or drive another person insane.

While the easiest way is to spend years of research, we know there are liches who got their powers in other ways. Phaegia, for example, was gifted with that condition by [Orcus](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Phaegia). While [Arazni](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Arazni) was turned into a lich against her will. [Gezbria](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Gezbria) was turned into a lich by being too close to corrupted ley lines for a long period. And I remember one case in the campaign setting books where several spellcasters became liches by sacrificing an entire species of sentient whales (it was only a few dozen members, but still).

Take a look at the [Eternal Apotheosis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-rules/occult-rituals/#Eternal_Apotheosis) ritual, you don't really have to construct your own phylactery, but provide *a* phylactery for the ritual.

Anyway, the methods exist, and not all of them had to research for the expensive phylactery. Just have a talk with your GM and you both could come up with something during the campain.

However, the lich corruption mystery does not say anything about discounting the creation of a phylactery, so **the *RAW* answer is no**. But personally, I would work with the player in a more suitable way of getting themselves killed while having their soul attached to an object to finish becoming a lich, since that is kind of the entire flavor of that mystery.

Comment: This is good information about becoming a lich, but doesn't address OP's actual question.

Comment: @Ifusaso It does mention other ways of becoming a Lich and that its not always a single specific cost, so with this the DM might be willing to work with me or something

Answer (score 0):

## No

The rules don't say this or anything like it.

This is the sort of thing where you might ask your DM to issue a house rule for you, assuming that your DM would be okay with your character becoming a lich at all.

But we're not your DM and we can't issue house rules for you.